# Is ATK4 in some stable state?

Tags: atk4

currently I am looking for a new PHP framework, with which I can create some powerful business logic applications. I stumbled over ATK4.
Since yesterday, I am trying to get a grip on this, but I must say it seems to me that the whole framework and its documentation is in some kind of unstable - or at least very beginner-unfriendly - state.

I mean I tried doing the DVD Rental example (with ATK4.2) and there are so many errors coming up (I did it all according to documentation). Then I realized that there is a new release, 4.3, which I tried then. But same problem here: The beginner documentation (the examples from the book) have so many errors in it or there are so incomplete.

Am I too dumb to find a decent example or is this really the way it is with ATK? I mean I really like the concept of ATK but with this kind of documentation I would think it will be very difficult for new developers to start using this framework for new projects.

Comment: If you're new to ATK then you definitely need to look at upcoming 4.3 version. It's not released officially yet, but it should be quite stable and usable. There are already multiple real-life projects running on v.4.3.

Comment: Speaking about documentation - it was major fail of ATK previously, but now there is completely new e-book available and you can take a look there - http://book.agiletoolkit.org/. If I'm not mistaken, then it is based on 4.3 version. And this is Google Groups of ATK4 - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/agile-toolkit-devel. It's also quite informative and helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Update 2017:

Several parts of Agile Toolkit (ATK4) have been refactored into stand-alone frameworks. The issues OP have outlined with poor code quality and lacking documentation have been addressed and explained in READMEs:

- http://github.com/atk4/data - Refactor of Model from Agile Toolkit
- http://github.com/atk4/ui - Refactor of UI widgets from Agile Toolkit

Both libraries can be used in conjunction with any other PHP framework.

As author of the original ATK framework and now Agile Data / Agile UI - I am always trying to support the core code and publish it under permissive license.

Comment: Thanks romans for the answer. I have seen the 4.3 version update. Also, I have used the book to get started. But there are actually some flaws in the code the way I see it. I have submitted one of the errors in a pull request on github. Which contact form do you mean from your page? The general one, or is there some specific form through which I can get directly in contact with you?

Comment: general one - i'll get it in my mailbox.